# My test is failing saying page_path function doesn't exist in Rumbl.Routers.Helpers

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

So I can't seem to figure out why my test is failing.

Error message is:

```
1) test require authentication on all actions (Rumbl.VideoControllerTest)
     test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:4
     ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Rumbl.Routers.Helpers.page_path/2 is undefined (module Rumbl.Routers.Helpers is not available)
     stacktrace:
       Rumbl.Routers.Helpers.page_path(%Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Adapters.Test.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{current_user: nil}, before_send: [#Function<0.101282891/1 in Plug.CSRFProtection.call/2>, #Function<4.74055627/1 in Phoenix.Controller.fetch_flash/2>, #Function<0.131660147/1 in Plug.Session.before_send/2>, #Function<1.60643777/1 in Plug.Logger.call/2>], body_params: %{}, cookies: %{}, halted: false, host: "www.example.com", method: "GET", owner: #PID<0.416.0>, params: %{}, path_info: ["manage", "videos", "new"], path_params: %{}, peer: {{127, 0, 0, 1}, 111317}, port: 80, private: %{Rumbl.Router => {[], %{}}, :phoenix_endpoint => Rumbl.Endpoint, :phoenix_flash => %{}, :phoenix_format => "html", :phoenix_pipelines => [:browser, :authenticate_user], :phoenix_recycled => true, :phoenix_route => #Function<15.17895686/1 in Rumbl.Router.match_route/4>, :phoenix_router => Rumbl.Router, :plug_session => %{}, :plug_session_fetch => :done, :plug_skip_csrf_protection => true}, query_params: %{}, query_string: "", remote_ip: {127, 0, 0, 1}, req_cookies: %{}, req_headers: [], request_path: "/manage/videos/new", resp_body: nil, resp_cookies: %{}, resp_headers: [{"cache-control", "max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"}, {"x-request-id", "ve978tecm111nf993e7nnjd9atl5892j"}, {"x-frame-options", "SAMEORIGIN"}, {"x-xss-protection", "1; mode=block"}, {"x-content-type-options", "nosniff"}], scheme: :http, script_name: [], secret_key_base: "509oRqKQNK7D/P43t6KZhu5jMhkWEJF455n+TS/Dve84JTYENxW08EqFwXedE9SI", state: :unset, status: nil}, :index)
       (rumbl) web/controllers/auth.ex:34: Rumbl.Auth.authenticate_user/2
       (rumbl) web/router.ex:1: Rumbl.Router.match_route/4
       (rumbl) web/router.ex:1: Rumbl.Router.do_call/2
       (rumbl) lib/rumbl/endpoint.ex:1: Rumbl.Endpoint.phoenix_pipeline/1
       (rumbl) lib/rumbl/endpoint.ex:1: Rumbl.Endpoint.call/2
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:224: Phoenix.ConnTest.dispatch/5
       test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:6: (test)
```

My unit test looks like:

```
defmodule Rumbl.VideoControllerTest do
  use Rumbl.ConnCase

  test "require authentication on all actions", %{conn: conn} do
    Enum.each([
        get(conn, video_path(conn, :new)),
        get(conn, video_path(conn, :index)),
        get(conn, video_path(conn, :show, "123")),
        get(conn, video_path(conn, :edit, "123")),
        put(conn, video_path(conn, :update, "123", %{})),
        post(conn, video_path(conn, :create, %{})),
        delete(conn, video_path(conn, :delete, "123")),
      ], fn conn ->
      assert html_response(conn, 302)
      assert conn.halted
    end)
  end
end
```

conn_case.ex file:

```
defmodule Rumbl.ConnCase do
  @moduledoc """
  This module defines the test case to be used by
  tests that require setting up a connection.

  Such tests rely on `Phoenix.ConnTest` and also
  import other functionality to make it easier
  to build and query models.

  Finally, if the test case interacts with the database,
  it cannot be async. For this reason, every test runs
  inside a transaction which is reset at the beginning
  of the test unless the test case is marked as async.
  """

  use ExUnit.CaseTemplate

  using do
    quote do
      # Import conveniences for testing with connections
      use Phoenix.ConnTest

      alias Rumbl.Repo
      import Ecto
      import Ecto.Changeset
      import Ecto.Query

      import Rumbl.Router.Helpers
      import Rumbl.TestHelpers

      # The default endpoint for testing
      @endpoint Rumbl.Endpoint
    end
  end

  setup tags do
    :ok = Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.checkout(Rumbl.Repo)

    unless tags[:async] do
      Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Rumbl.Repo, {:shared, self()})
    end

    {:ok, conn: Phoenix.ConnTest.build_conn()}
  end
end
```

Does anything stand out there?

Also please comment on how you would go about diagnosing this?

Comment: Your picking up `Rumbl.Routers.Helpers` somewhere. I think it should be `Rumbl.Router.Helpers`. No `s`. But I can't see where its being picked up. Check your `web.ex` file.

Comment: @StevePallen you the man thanks!  ok so a type great!

Comment: Where was the `Routers` being picked up from? I'd like to add an answer :)

Comment: In my Rumbl.Auth module (auth.ex) I had an alias that was ```alias Rumbl.Routers.Helpers```   yes please convert your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is indicating that module `Rumbl.Routers.Helpers` can't be found. Typically, Phoenix `Router` (no `s`) modules are not pluralized. Furthermore, you reference `import Rumbl.Router.Helpers` in the conn case. So it appears that you have imported or aliased `Rumbl.Routers` somewhere in your project.

If you search for `Routers` in your project, you should find the typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try following command, if you don't have a page_path in output, that would explain the error and you can add a page_path (by adding def index (.) method in PageController)

$ mix phx.routes

page_path GET / HrcPhxWeb.PageController :index
...